# How to link up calculations and QLineEdit

Tags: qt, calculator, qlineedit

I have a problem with managing to code the simple calculator.
I have two QLineEdits, which I want to connect together, do simple calculations as addition, multiplication, and then show the result in the third QLineEdit, [as shown in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oKJ5.png).

Comment: What is exactly your doubt? Can you attach your code, please?

Comment: I want to do a calculator with different calculations but to the point.  The user of a program writes for example how much he weights and how tall he is, as a result we get a BMI in the 3rd QLineEdit. And I don't really know now how and where put the necessary code. How to link them to read the variables, calculate them and show the result in the end.

Comment: No, I just wanted to ask what is the best way of achieving it. I can't figure out how to use the slots and signals in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the best components for such task are `QDoubleSpinBox` - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html (for float and double values) or `QSpinBox` - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html (for integers values). Add button with name "Addition" and connect slot on button signal `void QAbstractButton::clicked(bool checked = false)` (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked).
Your form will be like this:

[image: form]

The slot connected to "Addition" button clicked signal will be like this:

```
void MainWindow::slotPushButtonAdditionClicked(bool checked)
{
    Q_UNUSED(checked);
    ui->doubleSpinBoxResult->setValue(
                ui->doubleSpinBox1->value() +
                ui->doubleSpinBox2->value());
}
```